# jQuery UI draggable revert

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have 4 tables generated dynamically. There is two divs in each cell (td). All the divs are droppable. I dont know why but only the 2nd div accepts the draggable, the first one reverts it. There is no different between the two divs (exepts one has a "dotted" class).

Here is the jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/OMIbOGU/22/edit

**JS**

```
$("document").ready(function(){

  function init(){
    var table = $("<table></table>");
    $("body").append(table);
    for(var i=0 ;i < 9; i++){
      var row = $("<tr></tr>");
      var cell =  $("<td></td>");
      for(var j = 0;j<2;j++){
        var slot = $("<div></div>").addClass('slot');

        slot.droppable({
          accept: ".unassigned"
        });

        if (j!==1)
          slot.addClass("dotted");
        cell.append(slot);
      }
      row.append(cell);    
      table.append(row);

    }

    $(".unassigned").draggable({
      revert: "invalid",
      snap: "td div"
    });
  }
  for(var i = 0 ; i<4;i++)
  init();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you add

```
tolerance: 'touch'
```

to the droppable it works.  Which points to it being more of a css issue than one with the script.

[Updated JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/OMIbOGU/32/edit)